# How to created nested directories using objective c in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xml, directory

I am new to objective c. I need to create nested folders inside document folder which is default path. Like Documents/folder1/folder2/folder3/user.xml but here one thing folder3 name giving dynamically but i am not getting how to pass folder name dynamically while creating folders inside default manager. Whatever i will be created should read and check that user.xml file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using NSFileManager. First check that the file does not exist using `fileExistsAtPath:`, giving it the full path of the xml file.

If it does not exist, use `createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:` to create your **folder3** structure, setting `withIntermediateDirectories` to YES.

Then you can create your **user.xml** file inside **folder3**.

Comment: How to pass folder name dynamically in plae of folder 3?

Comment: If you have a string (e.g. `rootDir`) containing a 'root' directory, and a string containing the dynamic part (e.g. `endFolder`) you can create a new path using: `NSString *fullPath = [rootDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:endFolder];` Use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` to get the app's document root path on iOS (there are no end of examples of how to do that).

Comment: How to read the file through this path ?Even while reading i have to pass dynamic folder name to the path.

Comment: Use NSString's `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` (doc here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1497269-stringwithcontentsoffile).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
   NSError *err;
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [pathArr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourDesiredPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"folder1/folder2/folder3/user.xml "];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:yourDesiredPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:yourDesiredPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&err];
    NSLog(@"folder created at path : %@",yourDesiredPath);
}
```

Comment: I used same created folders but not able to compare created folders with NSFileManager its always showing nil.